# Showing that a sequence converges a.s. given the convergence of a random subsequence

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Suppose we have a sequence of r.v's $\{\tau_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ such that $\Delta \tau_n = \tau_n - \tau_{n - 1}$ are i.i.d. and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \tau_n/n = c$ a.s. for a known $0 < c < \infty$. Suppose further that we have another collection of r.v's $\{L_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ and we're given that $\lim_{n \to \infty} L_{\tau_n}/n = \gamma$ a.s., for a known $0 < \gamma < \infty$. I want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} L_n/n = \gamma/c$ a.s.

---

Here is my attempt:

Theorem: Let $Y_n \to Y$ a.s. and $N_t \to \infty $ a.s., then $Y_{N_t} \to Y$ a.s.

Consider the sequence $s_t = \lfloor t/c \rfloor$. Clearly $s_t \to \infty$ a.s., so $\tau_n/n \to c $ a.s. implies $\tau_{s_t}/s_{t} \to c$ a.s. by the Theorem. From there, we use $c s_t \to t$ to get $\tau_{s_t} \to t$ a.s.

Next, $L_{\tau_n}/n \to \gamma$ a.s. implies $L_{\tau_{s_t}}/s_{t} \to \gamma$ a.s., by the Theorem. Using the result of the previous paragraph for $\tau_{s_t}$, $L_{t}/s_{t} \to \gamma$ a.s. and then dividing both sides by $c$ gives $L_{t}/t \to \gamma/c$ a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is false.

Let $\tau_n=2n$; the differences $\tau_n-\tau_{n-1}$ are iid constant $2$. Also, $\tau_n/n\to 2$ almost surely.

Let $L_{n}=n$ when $n$ is even, and $L_n=0$ when $n$ is odd. Then
$$
\lim_n L_{\tau_n}/n=2n/n=2,
$$
but $\lim_n L_n/n$ does not exist, as $L_n/n$ alternates between $2$ and $0$.

Comment: Would it save me if I knew $0 \leq L_n - L_{n - 1} \leq 2$?

Comment: I suppose the problem is that without bounding $\Delta L_{n}$ you can get arbitrarily large variations. But if it is bounded by a constant, then $L_{\tau_{s_t}} = L_{t} + \mathcal{O}(1)$ since $t - c \leq c \lfloor t/c\rfloor \leq t$ which fixes the proof?

Comment: @Mr.G Yeah, that seems about right. I think you can figure out how to make it rigorous. A good trick is $L_n/n=(L_n/L_{\tau_n})\cdot (L_{\tau_n}/n)$.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking a look.